# Split each element in array into object after certain character

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop

I'm new to node.js and javascript. I have the following array:

```
var oldarray = [
  'name1\tstreet\tperson\tphone1\tphone2\nname2\street2\tperson1\tphone82\tphone3\n'
]
```

Note, this is a single element array. First, I require the array to contain a  new element after each new line first, then, re-format like below:

```
let headers = {
  name: "",
  street: "",
  person: "",
  phone 1 "",
  phone 2 ""
}
```

How can I parse through each element (after creating a new element after each +), and assign an object within an array after each instance of `\`

The desired output is this:

```
[{
  name: 'name1',
  street: 'street2',
  person: 'person1',
  phone1: 'phone82 ',
  phone2: 'phone3'
},
{
  name: 'name2',
  street: 'street2',
  person: 'person1',
  phone1: 'phone1 ',
  phone2: 'phone2'
}]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There's only one element in the original array, do you realize that?

Comment: Correct, it is a single element.

Comment: Typo, my bad. @Sven.hig

Comment: What does " after each + first" mean? Because as far as JS knows _there is no + symbol_, there are only the characters in your string. Did you mean "after each newline"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You are right. I made another typo, sorry.

Comment: So what did you actually try? Becuase this looks like a standard "split on `\n`, and then for each of those, split on `\t`", which is hardly challenging code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each `oldarray` value on `\n` and then `\t` into `newarray`, and then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build an object from each `newarray` value, combining the split values with each key from `headers`:

```js
var oldarray = [
  'name1\tstreet\tperson\tphone1\tphone2\n' +
  'name2\tstreet2\tperson1\tphone82\tphone3\n'
]

let newarray = [];

oldarray.forEach(s => s.trim().split('\n').map(v => newarray.push(v.split('\t'))));

let headers = {
  'name': "",
  'street': "",
  'person': "",
  'phone 1': "",
  'phone 2': ""
}

let keys = Object.keys(headers);

out = newarray.map(s => Object.fromEntries(s.map((v, i) => [keys[i], v])));
console.log(out);
```

Comment: There aren't two elements in the original array if you read the question carefully...

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same structure for all items in `OLD_ARRAY` you can use `map`, `filter` and `reduce` in order to manipulate your input.

So what I did?

1. In case that you have multiple strings like the example input (more than 1 array item) I convert it to sub-arrays of each string by using `map` and `split` by `\n`, which is your string separator. Than I filtered it by strings that are not empty (becasue that you have a post-fix of `\n` as well).
2. From each sub-array I extracted all the contacts using `extractContacts` function - it splites the sub-array by your separaotr, `\t`, and map it according to your contacts temaplte.
3. Since it's a format of array of arrays, I used reduce to concat all the arrays together

```js
const OLD_ARRAY = [
  'name1\tstreet\tperson\tphone1\tphone2\n' +
  'name2\tstreet2\tperson1\tphone82\tphone3\n'
];

function extractContacts(templates) {
  return templates.map(t => t.split('\t'))
    .map(details => ({
      name: details[0],
      street: details[1],
      person: details[2],
      phone1: details[3],
      phone2: details[4]
    }));
}

let contacts = OLD_ARRAY.map(str => str.split('\n').filter(str => str !== ''))
  .map(template => extractContacts(template))
  .reduce((a, acc) => acc.concat(a), []);

console.log(contacts)
```

Comment: Notice there aren't two elements in the original array if you read the question carefully

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think the op had a typo, and even if he didn't, it's just changing the `+` to `,` to achieve the array-like format

Comment: It's possible that is only intermediate output after parsing JSON from an HTTP request, for example, and that the OP has no control over the format of the input. You can't assume that it's trivially possible to change the input format, because the question could be simplifying a lot of things for the sake of isolating the part they need help with.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You are right, I fixed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First split the array by `\n` to get individual paths and then split them by `\t`, and use `reduce` to create new header objects from each subarray

```js
var oldarray = [
  'name1\tstreet\tperson\tphone1\tphone2\n' +
    'name2\tstreet2\tperson1\tphone82\tphone3\n' +
    'name4\tstreet4\tperson4\tphone84\tphone4\n'
]
arr = oldarray.flatMap(o => o.split("\n"))
c = arr.map(o => o.split("\t"))
c.pop()
result = c.reduce((acc,[name, street, person, phone1, phone2],i) => {
   acc = [...acc,{name:name,street:street,person:person,phone1:phone1,phone2:phone2}]
           return acc
},[])
console.log(result)
```